# Criar ODBC Connection

Tags: c#, windows, connectionstring, conexão

Estou realizando a integração do meu sistema com a base de dados do [SEFIP](http://www.caixa.gov.br/empresa/fgts-empresas/SEFIP-GRF/Paginas/default.aspx).
A base de dados é em Interbase (.gbd).
Consigo realizar a conexão com o banco de dados via Microsoft Access normalmente. Criei uma conexão ODBC manualmente (Executar: odbcad32 ou Ferramentas Administrativas -> Fontes de Dados ODBC) e consigo conectar meu sistema utilizando o [OdbcConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
OdbcConnection OdbcConn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=Sefip");
OdbcConn.Open();
```

Dessa forma eu realizo as consultas normalmente. O problema é que irei utilizar essa integração em muitos clientes, então fica inviável criar a conexão ODBC manualmente em todos. Para evitar fazer isso, estou tentando criar a conexão pelo sistema. [Essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/336815/4843158) mostra uma forma de fazer isso, porém o usuário e senha não são passados à conexão.

Nesta parte era para preencher todos os dados. Apesar dos dados estarem em suas respectivas variáveis, não é salvo na no DNS.

```
 var dsnKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBC_INI_REG_PATH + dsnName);
        if (dsnKey == null) throw new Exception("ODBC Registry key for DSN was not created");
        dsnKey.SetValue("Database", database);
        dsnKey.SetValue("Description", description);
        dsnKey.SetValue("Driver", driverPath);
        dsnKey.SetValue("LastUser", Environment.UserName);
        dsnKey.SetValue("Server", server);
        dsnKey.SetValue("Trusted_Connection", trustedConnection ? "Yes" : "No");
```

O código completo pode ser visto abaixo:

```
 private const string ODBC_INI_REG_PATH = "SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\";
        private const string ODBCINST_INI_REG_PATH = "SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBCINST.INI\\";

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new DSN entry with the specified values. If the DSN exists, the values are updated.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dsnName">Name of the DSN for use by client applications</param>
        /// <param name="description">Description of the DSN that appears in the ODBC control panel applet</param>
        /// <param name="server">Network name or IP address of database server</param>
        /// <param name="driverName">Name of the driver to use</param>
        /// <param name="trustedConnection">True to use NT authentication, false to require applications to supply username/password in the connection string</param>
        /// <param name="database">Name of the datbase to connect to</param>
        public static void CreateDSN(string dsnName, string description, string server, string driverName,
            bool trustedConnection, string database)
        {
            // Lookup driver path from driver name
            var driverKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBCINST_INI_REG_PATH + driverName);
            if (driverKey == null)
                throw new Exception(string.Format("ODBC Registry key for driver '{0}' does not exist", driverName));
            string driverPath = driverKey.GetValue("Driver").ToString();

            // Add value to odbc data sources
            var datasourcesKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBC_INI_REG_PATH + "ODBC Data Sources");
            if (datasourcesKey == null) throw new Exception("ODBC Registry key for datasources does not exist");
            datasourcesKey.SetValue(dsnName, driverName);

            // Create new key in odbc.ini with dsn name and add values
            var dsnKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBC_INI_REG_PATH + dsnName);
            if (dsnKey == null) throw new Exception("ODBC Registry key for DSN was not created");
            dsnKey.SetValue("Database", database);
            dsnKey.SetValue("Description", description);
            dsnKey.SetValue("Driver", driverPath);
            dsnKey.SetValue("LastUser", Environment.UserName);
            dsnKey.SetValue("Server", server);
            dsnKey.SetValue("Trusted_Connection", trustedConnection ? "Yes" : "No");
        }
```

Ao criar manualmente, esses são os dados em uma conexão funcionando:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao criar pelo sistema o restante dos dados estão vazios, dessa forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minhas dúvidas são:
Exite algo errado com o código para não preencher os dados da conexão, mesmo os valores estando no `SetValue`?
Existe algum provider para Entity Framework ou Dapper para realizar essa conexão?
Existe alguma forma de obter a string de conexão do `new OdbcConnection("DSN=Sefip");` para eu poder utilizar no [FbConnection()](http://sourceforge.net/p/firebird/NETProvider/ci/75316e13889036a88d6d961037b6c8f3cd662712/tree/source/FirebirdSql/Data/FirebirdClient/FbConnection.cs)?

---

Para quem desconhece, [este tutorial](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc879308(v=sql.105).aspx) explica como configurar fonte de dados ODBC manualmente.

Comment: Eu sei que é idiota, mas tu deu um `close`? Porque no pedaço do código que tu mostrou não tais executando isso no `dnskey`.

Comment: @DarkHyudrA Eu só "crio" a conexão se ela não existir. Essa verificação vem antes de abrir a conexão. Depois de abrir funciona normalmente. E sim, dei `close` sim.

Comment: @AndreMesquita Não cheguei a testar ainda. Vou testar e te retorno

Comment: Use ADO DB e evite criar DSN. Além de mais simples de fazer, é mais rápido. Dê uma olhada no site [ConnectionStrings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/firebird/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução foi alterar o método `CreateDNS` para passar os parâmetros que restavam, inclusive o driver do Interbase. O método ficou assim:

```
 public static void CreateDSN(string dsnName, string description, string server, string driverName,
            bool trustedConnection, string database, string user, string password, string client)
        {
            // Lookup driver path from driver name
            var driverKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBCINST_INI_REG_PATH + driverName);
            if (driverKey == null)
                throw new Exception(string.Format("ODBC Registry key for driver '{0}' does not exist", driverName));
            string driverPath = driverKey.GetValue("Driver").ToString();

            // Add value to odbc data sources
            var datasourcesKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBC_INI_REG_PATH + "ODBC Data Sources");
            if (datasourcesKey == null) throw new Exception("ODBC Registry key for datasources does not exist");
            datasourcesKey.SetValue(dsnName, driverName);

            // Create new key in odbc.ini with dsn name and add values
            var dsnKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBC_INI_REG_PATH + dsnName);
            if (dsnKey == null) throw new Exception("ODBC Registry key for DSN was not created");
            dsnKey.SetValue("DBName", database);
            dsnKey.SetValue("Description", description);
            dsnKey.SetValue("Driver", driverPath);
            dsnKey.SetValue("LastUser", Environment.UserName);
            dsnKey.SetValue("Server", server);
            dsnKey.SetValue("User", user);
            dsnKey.SetValue("Password", password);
            dsnKey.SetValue("Client", client);
            dsnKey.SetValue("Trusted_Connection", trustedConnection ? "Yes" : "No");
        }
```